# Google Chrome is not Downloading/Installing in Windows server 2016, I've only Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, server

Internet Explorer working too much slow i need google chrome in my windows server. I am unable to download installer with Internet explore. Is there any other way to install Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install google chrome via Powershell.

- Go to start and search powershell and open with administrator
- Run the following command to install google chrome

```
 $LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
```